# Rails counting through relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, relationship

I'm having problems getting my brain around this.

I have four models: `Account` has many-> `List` has many-> `ListItem` <-belongs to `Category`

I need to get a list of the top-n Categories and the quantity count -- the ones that have the most related `ListItem`s. To make it more complex, the Account has a "role" (say, 'team lead' and 'manager', and the count needs to be separated by that role. To summarize, I need this:

```
Top 5 Categories for Team Lead: Category122 (74), Category342 (67), Category22 (52), Category992 (50), Category12 (47) 
Top 5 Categories for Manager: Category1 (174), Category32 (112), Category22 (88), Category92 (73), Category5 (72)
```

I keep trying to form scopes or write class methods to generate these numbers and don't get far before I get confused.

Anyone know how this type of thing can be calculated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your `Account` model:

```
has_many :list_items, :through => :lists
```

Then you can do this:

```
a = Account.first
a.list_items.joins(:category).group("categories.name").count
# => {"foo"=>1, "bar"=>2}
```

**EDIT**

```
@categories = Category.select("categories.name AS name, accounts.role AS role, count(list_items.id) AS count")
.joins(:list_items => {:list => :account})
.group("categories.name, accounts.role")
.order("count desc")
.limit(5)

@categories[0].role
# => Team Leader
@categories[0].count
# => 5
```

You'll have to add the category fields to the select, and the query looks something like:

```
SELECT categories.name, accounts.role, count(list_items.id) 
FROM list_items INNER JOIN lists ON lists.id = list_items.list_id 
INNER JOIN categories ON categories.id = list_items.category_id 
INNER JOIN accounts ON lists.account_id = accounts.id 
GROUP BY categories.name, accounts.role;
```

Comment: Right, but then I'd have to go through all the accounts (of which there are thousands), and sum up the counts. The idea isn't to get it for a single account, but to get the top-5s as an overall idea of the system as a whole. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. The SQL query is quite intense for a lot of records. I've edited my answer - maybe it will help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
top_team_lead_categories = Category.all(
  :joins => {:list_item => {:list => :account}},
  :select => "categories.*, sum(if(list_items.category_id = categories.id, 1, 0)) as list_items_count",
  :conditions => ['accounts.role =?', 'team lead'],
  :group => 'categories.id',
  :order => 'list_items_count desc'
)
```

Comment: If I leave the second line as `:joins => {:list_item...`, I get the error `Association named 'list_item' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?`. If I change it to `list_items`, I get this error (similar for both Postgres and SQLite: `ERROR:  function if(boolean, integer, integer) does not exist`. Thanks for the answer -- I think this is pretty close.

Comment: That joins assumes a many-to-one association between `category` and `list_item`, but from your error I think I have the association wrong. The 2nd error is probably because I gave you a MySQL function. I think the Postgres version of sum if is `sum(case when list_items.category_id = categories.id then 1 else 0 end)`